# Download to VMware

Tags: vmware

I burned an ISO disk of ubuntu 12.10 to boot into VMware. It downloads successfully but the icons do not appear on the left side of the screen like they should. I am not sure if it is the VMware player causing the problem or if it is in the ISO file I downloaded?

My current OS on my notebook is Widows 7 Home Premium 64 bit.

Comment: Why exactly would you burn an iso, if you use it in a virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be a problem in the .iso itself ,

simply you can check the .iso file you downloaded by utorrent (Force recheck)

if the .iso is ok 
try reburn it again increase disk space for ubuntu and carefully read the steps when you burn on Vmware :)